# Can you have identical react Router path and Router exact path?

Tags: react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

In the instance of using React Router to create routes that are associated with displaying specific components. Is the following an example of a way in which you could use React Router to have a nav bar displayed across all pages (including the home page) while also specifying only the '/' path to display the home component.

```
class App extends Component{
  render(){
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
           <Route exact path ='/' component={Home}/>
           <Route path ='/' component={Nav}/>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm attempting to learn about React Router and have not seen an example exploit this or specifically prohibit it. So I was wondering if there was a case that you could/should or could/should not use it.

Comment: If you want the nav bar displayed on all pages then you don’t really need a Route component for it. You can just render it directly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I guess, to your point, my example isn't exactly the best use case. The question is more on the conceptual level of CAN you use exact path and path with the same path defined?

Comment: Oh I see. Yes you can have both. All routes will be matched. Wrapping them with a **Switch** component would allow only rendering the first matched route.